# Pass in an array of values to update multiple rows via one raw query

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using a raw query with sequelize to update multiple rows with one query in my postgres DB. For example:

```
update customers_table as c set
    name = c2.name
from (values
    (66, 'Joe'),
    (70, 'Ann')
) as c2(id, name)
where c2.id = c.id;
```

In this example, two rows with the ids `66` and `70` will have their names updated.

But how do I pass in data to be updated as an array in nodejs via sequelizejs raw query? For example (this doesn't work, but I'm trying to get at what it is I'm trying to do):

```
const arrayOfData = [[66, 'Joe'], [70, 'Ann']];

const query = 
`update customers_table as c set
    name = c2.name
from (values
    ${arrayOfData}
) as c2(id, name)
where c2.id = c.id;`;

const update = sequelize.query(query).spread((results, metadata) => {
    return results;
});
```

Comment: And one more thing: shouldn't your `arrayOfData` format would be something like this: `const arrayOfData = [[66, 'Joe'], [70, 'Ann']];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If number of elements in `arrayOfData` are constant, you can use this syntax:

```
db.query('update customers_table as c set
    name = c2.name
from (values
    (?),(?)
) as c2(id, name)
where c2.id = c.id', { replacements: arrayOfData })
```

Otherwise, you can simply use the following snippet:

```
const values = arrayOfData.map(row =>  `(${row.join(',')})`).join(',')
db.query(`update customers_table as c set
    name = c2.name
from (values
    ${values}
) as c2(id, name)
where c2.id = c.id`)
```

You can learn more about Sequelize raw query from its [official documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/raw-queries.html)